# Handling an "Inventory" (complex associations) with django + appengine

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a web application to manage a "game".
Here are the models:

```
class Character(db.Model):
    # Bio
    name = db.StringProperty()
    player = db.StringProperty()
    level = db.IntegerProperty()

class Item(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    description = db.StringProperty()
    value = db.StringProperty()

class Inventory(db.Model):
    character = db.ReferenceProperty(Character,required=True,collection_name="inventory")
    item = db.ReferenceProperty(Item,required=True,collection_name="inventory")
    quantity = db.IntegerProperty()
equipped = db.BooleanProperty()
```

I've an `Item` database, and when I add a character I want to manage its `Inventory`.
I've tried `ModelForm`s but they can't handle this sort of things. My idea is to display the complete `Item` list, each Item with an associated form quantity,equipped. Something like:

```
Sword :
  quantity ___
  equipped _
Armor :
  quantity ___
  equipped _
```

But, how to ship additional informations in forms?

P.S. I'm sorry that the question is dumb and not general, but I couldn't find the keywords to generalize it..

Comment: are you asking how to display this in an html form? it looks like your model does what you want it to so i assume that's not your question.

Comment: yes, my problem is the html "form" stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you want to show the Inventory of a Character in a form and place the form of the Character at the same page, you should check out inline formsets [the doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)

Using inline formsets you can do something like this:

```
character= get_object_or_404(Character, pk=character_id)
InventoryInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Character, Inventory, max_num=1)
classificationformset = ClassificationInlineFormSet(instance=character)
```

Out of this form you can manage your items, for example if you have a ManyToMany Relationship to your Items model you can handle them with ajax-filtered-fields [link](http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-filtered-fields/)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

you will want to look at inline formsets.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets